# XCode UI Testing: Unable to find test runner app containing test bundle path

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have written UI Tests in XCode 7.3.1 on a dedicated target. I can record a UI test but if I try to launch it (all tests or a single one), I got the following error :

> Unable to find test runner app containing test bundle path /Users/dle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Keecoach-exynmciqyehgmxcfxhkpksrqifsb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DemoKeecoachUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/DemoKeecoachUITests.app

[image: The error in XCode]

I do not really understand the message except that it appears a runner app has to launch the tests and that runner app is not existing. This `DemoKeecoachUITests-Runner.app` does not actually exist on my disk.

I cannot find anybody else mentionning the problem anywhere... I get the same error if I launch the tests in command line with `xctool`. I have the same problem on other computers, but I do not have the problem on other project, so it is related to the project. Any clue ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it!

Was due to the `Wrapper Extension` build setting. It was set to `app` for the project and so inherited for each target. I switched it to nothing for the projet, `app` for the application target and `xctest` for the test targets.

Now the generated binaries for tests are `ABCTests.xctest` and not `ABCTests.app` anymore. It was probably like this from a long time, but I don't know for what reason...

Comment: [how-do-i-change-a-targets-wrapper-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40569895/how-do-i-change-a-targets-wrapper-extension-in-xcode-8-1)