# How do I change a target's wrapper extension in xcode 8.1?

Tags: xcode, service

I am developing a standalone service as outlined here: http://www.notesfromandy.com/2013/04/05/writing-a-service-bundle/

The author recommends to change the wrapper extension to .service under the project menu, but in xcode 8 this functionality has been moved/removed. How would I go about changing this setting in xcode 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Click on the project name on the left hand side under the project navigator, then select build settings and cmd+F for wrapper. It is listed there as an editable attribute.